# PostgreQL update data from Json field which of type multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql

I was finding the query that update the data from table of column which of json type.

My table looks like:

```
ID |    Details

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1  | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_reviewed": "false"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

2  | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_reviewed": "false"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

3  | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_reviewed": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

4  | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_reviewed": "false"}, "default_locale": "en"}}
```

I want to update those row whose is_reviewed = false to true.

Output:-

```
ID |    Details

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1  | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_reviewed": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

2  | {"_translated": {"en_US": {"is_reviewed": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

3  | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_reviewed": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}

4  | {"_translated": {"en_CA": {"is_reviewed": "true"}, "default_locale": "en"}}
```

Please someone can help me this query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonb_set` ( Postgres 9.5+)

```
UPDATE t SET details =
jsonb_set(details::jsonb, '{_translated,en_US,is_reviewed}','"true"') where id = 1;
UPDATE t SET details =
jsonb_set(details::jsonb, '{_translated,en_US,is_reviewed}','"true"') where id = 2;
UPDATE t SET details =
jsonb_set(details::jsonb, '{_translated,en_CA,is_reviewed}','"true"') where id = 4;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c7b780c3ceeb5f1e8390c7b019018436)